# Azure Data Factory - Copy Data Upsert only updating a single row at a time

Tags: azure-data-factory, upsert

I'm using Data Factory (well synapse pipelines) to ingest data from sources into a staging layer.  I am using the Copy Data activity with UPSERT.  However i found the performance of incrementally loading large tables particularly slow so i did some digging.

So my incremental load brought in 193k new/modified records from the source. These get stored in the transient staging/landing table that the copy data activity creates in the database in the background.  In this table it adds a  column called BatchIdentifier, however the batch identifier value is different for every row.

[image]

Profiling the load i can see individual statements issued for each batchidentifier so effectively its processing the incoming data row by row rather than using a batch process to do the same thing.
I tried setting the sink writebatchsize property on copy data activity to 10k but that doesn't make any difference.

Has anyone else come across this, or a better way to perform a dynamic upsert without having to specify all the columns in advance (which i'm really hoping to avoid)

This is the SQL statement issued 193k times on my load as an example.

Does a check to see if the record exists in the target table, if so performs an update otherwise performs an insert. logic makes sense but its performing this on a row by row basis when this could just be done in bulk.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your primary key definition in the source the same as in the sink?

I just ran into this same behavior when the columns in the source and destination tables used different columns.

It also appears ADF/Synapse does not use MERGE for upserts, but its own IF EXISTS THEN UPDATE ELSE INSERT logic so there may be something behind the scenes making it select single rows for those BatchId executions.